# How to unselect all elements which are Not input fields

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, select, jquery-selectors

I have alot of large images on the page and when the user drags the cursor over them the blue selected highlight overcasts the images and won't easily go away. How can I use [this plugin](https://github.com/mathiasbynens/noSelect-jQuery-Plugin) (the noSelect jQuery-Plugin)

```
$.fn.noSelect = function(){
        var none = 'none';
        return this.bind('selectstart dragstart mousedown', function() {
                return false;
        }).css({
                'MozUserSelect': none,
                'WebkitUserSelect': none,
                'userSelect': none
        });
};
```

and find the elements which are selected and unselect them, all except forms, textareas, and input fields which need to be selected in order to function.

Maybe something involving the `:selected` [jQuery selector](http://api.jquery.com/selected-selector/)?

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

The `:selected` selector is used for select statements, ie. lists/options.

Why don't you just add the appropriate CSS to the images you don't want selected? 
If there is some drag event you're listening for, just apply it to all images upon drag start.

```
var isDragging = false;
$(document).ready(function(){
        $("img").noSelect();
        //or
        $(document).mousedown(function(){
             isDragging = true;
             $("img").noSelect();
        }).mouseup(function(){
             isDragging = false;
             $("img").makeSelectable();
        });
});
```